# Multiple values of <option>

Tags: javascript

I would like to put multiple values in  tag within select, so I could adress precisely one or few items.

Example:

```
<select id="select1">
<option value="pf, nn">NN</option>
<option value="pf, x2, jj">JJ</option>
<option value="pf, uu">UU</option>
<option value="pf, x2, oo">OO</option>
<option value="tt">TT</option>
<option value="rr">RR</option>
</select>
```

In my js I got that one function that depend on one value that is common for many items:

```
if (document.getElementById("select1").value = "pf";) {
// do something;
}
if (document.getElementById("select1").value = "x2";) {
// do some-other-thing;
}
```

But I don't want to use (cos' and with more options gonna get messy)

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById("select1").value
if (sel1="nn" || sel1="jj" || sel1="uu" || sel1="oo") {
// do something;
}
if (sel1="jj" || sel1="oo") {
// do some-other-thing;
}
```

Neverthelesst I need to be able to set item by precise one value

```
if (document.somethingelse = true) {
document.getElementById("select1").value = "oo";)
}
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this? Maybe use some other "value-like" attribute of option (but which?)?
Only JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `selectedOpt.value.split(",").includes("sth")` code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    selectedChange($("#select1")[0])
});

function selectedChange(val) {
    var selectedOpt = val.options[val.selectedIndex];
    var status1 = selectedOpt.value.split(",").includes("x2");
    var status2 = selectedOpt.value.split(",").includes("pf");
    console.log(status1);
    console.log(status2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" onchange="selectedChange(this)">
<option value="pf,nn">NN</option>
<option value="pf,x2,jj">JJ</option>
<option value="pf,uu">UU</option>
<option value="pf,x2,oo">OO</option>
<option value="tt">TT</option>
<option value="rr">RR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: SOrry, no, JS only as I stated in topic. JQuery not possible